Mechanism for reduction with dihydropyridine derivative as reducing agent
I want to reduce a carbon-carbon double bond in an α,β-unsaturated ketone with a dihydropyridine derivative as the reducing agent. I have the following two questions:
Question 1: I predicted a mechanism (image below) and I wonder whether this   mechanism is reasonable and chemically correct. Or is there a better alternative? I could not find a mechanism in literature. My main concern with my mechanism is that the enolate is protonated at the β-carbon (a soft nucleophilic centre), while $\ce{H+}$ is a hard electrophile. Would this mean the enolate oxygen (a hard nucleophilic centre) is more likely to be protonated and an enol is formed instead?
Question 2:  I am using benzylammonium acetate as catalyst. How does this salt serves its catalytic role in this reaction? Does it stabilize the charged intermediates formed in this reaction? Or might it have another function?


Regarding question 1: I realize that the site of protonation is more likely to be the oxygen, and keto-enol tautomerisation will favour the ketone. With this adjustment, is the overall reaction mechanism reasonable?

I think the main issue is how hydride is donated - these things don't just pop-off ;)

Doesn't the removal of the hydride result in an aromatic system, which could be the driving force behind this step? If not, what would be a better alternative?

Well, yeah, but if there's catalyst, then likely for this.

The catalyst works by stabilizing the charges in the intermediates?

Hydride transfer has to be concerted. Pyridine cation doesn't need much stabilisation, but binding to carboxylate would help, I guess. Perhaps making all of it concerted - both hydride and proton donation. I don't know, perhaps nobody knows the details for sure.
